# Reading values from Json file

Tags: python, json, file, python-import, py2neo

I am trying to read an attribute from a Json file using this: 
    `d['text']['entities']['mention'][0]['screen_name']`

Json File

```
{
    "text" : {
        "content" : "@narendramodi Did u even know the fare of metro has been increased by 65%",

        "entities" : {
            "user_mentions" : [ ],
            "mention" : [
                {
                    "indices" : [
                        0,
                        13
                    ],
                    "id_str" : "18839785",
                    "screen_name" : "narendramodi",
                    "name" : "Narendra Modi",
                    "id" : 18839785
                }
            ],
            "hashtags" : [ ],
        },

    }
}
```

I am trying to load many json files in Neo4J Database using py2neo library.

While accesing    `d['text']['entities']['mention'][0]['screen_name']`
in one of the json file in which `"mention" : [ ],` mention field is empty it says

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Error is pretty obvious but how should I handle this?

Comment: It work perfect in my computer (python 3.6), the value is `'narendramodi'` without any problem.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me as well. Is this all you have in JSON file? I am using Python 2.7..

Comment: There seems a mismatch between the json you posted and the json your program is reading.

Comment: Just got to know the real problem.
**Please see the edited version of problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `try/except` block. Like

```
try:
  data = d['text']['entities']['mention'][0]['screen_name']
  ...
except IndexError:
  data = None # or handle this case in other way
```

Comment: @Aman Kumar You are welcome) If my answer is helpful you could mark it as right answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this -

```
   mentions = d.get('text',{}).get('entities',{}).get('mention' ,[])
   if len(mentions)>0:
        print(mentions[0].get('screen_name',None))
   else:
        print(None)
```

Comment: string wouldn't produce `IndexError: list index out of range`. Also, you don't convert it into a "json object", but *python objects*. JSON is a text serialization format.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ,  I have tested this code and it is working , looks like json is wrong and having some extra ',' in the json .

Comment: Yes, I know the code works, but this answer doesn't address the OP's problem, which is a list throwing an `IndexError`. Indeed, the code in the OPs question *works*, so obviously, this isn't the issue.

Comment: Again **this has nothing to do with the error the OP is encountering, which is caused by indexing a list out of range**. There was a typo in the sample data the OP provided, but that isn't the root issue.

Comment: Just got to know the real problem. 

**Please see the edited version of problem.**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , can you see it now ? thanks for help!